# How can I know what Widget call the Handler or Event?

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwtp

I'm using GWT-Platform in my project, and I want to check what Widget called some Handler, for example, a BlurHandler.

The reason for my question is below. This BlurHandler is registred by four TextField.

```
@Override
public void addFormatTextBoxListener(BlurHandler handler) {
    tbAlt.addBlurHandler(handler);
    tbLat.addBlurHandler(handler);
    tbMedida.addBlurHandler(handler);
    tbLong.addBlurHandler(handler);
}
```

In my Presenter I want to find what field(Widget) lost the focus(Result of BlurEvent).

```
getView().addFormatTextBoxListener(new BlurHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
            doFormatTextBox();
        }
    });
private void doFormatTextBox() {
    //who called me???
}
```

The method doFormatTextBox will be called when one of the four Widget's lost focus. But what Widget losted focus?

Comment: Please mention your GWT and GWT-Platform version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redading the Event API (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html)
it seams as though `Element e1 = event.getTarget()`  and then doing `if (e1.equals(widget1.getElement())){//do stuff...}` should work.

This is assuming BlurEvent extends `com.google.gwt.user.client.Event` which I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Even Handler is not available in GWT 1.5 . It was introduced in later versions of GWT. The premise of your solution is correct though.

Comment: I'm using both gwt and gwtp latest version. I'll try your solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It works :D but instead of 
     `event.getTarget();`
use `event.getRelativeElement();`